# splitting filename text by underscores using R

Tags: r, text, split, filenames

In R I'd like to take a collection of file names in the format below and return the number to the right of the second underscore (this will always be a number) and the text string to the right of the third underscore (this will be combinations of letters and numbers).

I have file names in this format:

```
HELP_PLEASE_4_ME
```

I want to extract the number `4` and the text `ME`

I'd then like to create a new field within my data frame where these two types of data can be stored.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Try strsplit('HELP_PLEASE_4_ME', '_') or wait for some regex expert to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `regexec` and `regmatches` to pull out the patterns:

```
matches <- regmatches(df$a, regexec("^.*?_.*?_([0-9]+)_([[:alnum:]]+)$", df$a))
df[c("match.1", "match.2")] <- t(sapply(matches, `[`, -1)) # first result for each match is full regular expression so need to drop that.
```

Produces:

```
                 a match.1 match.2
1 HELP_PLEASE_4_ME       4      ME
2  SOS_WOW_3_Y34OU       3   Y34OU
```

This will break if any rows don't have the expected structure, but I think that is what you want to happen (i.e. be alerted that your data is not what you think it is). `strsplit` based approaches will require additional checking to ensure that your data is what you think it is.

And the data:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c("HELP_PLEASE_4_ME", "SOS_WOW_3_Y34OU"), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know that you want the text that comes after the second and third underscore, you could use `strsplit` and take the third and fourth result.

```
> x <- "HELP_PLEASE_4_ME"
> spl <- unlist(strsplit(x, "_"))[3:4]
> data.frame(string = x, under2 = spl[1], under3 = spl[2])
##             string under2 under3
## 1 HELP_PLEASE_4_ME      4     ME
```

Then for longer vectors, you could do something like the last two lines here.

```
## set up some data
> word1 <- c("HELLO", "GOODBYE", "HI", "BYE")
> word2 <- c("ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR")
> nums <- 20:23
> word3 <- c("ME", "YOU", "THEM", "US")
> XX <-paste0(word1, "_", word2, "_", nums, "_", word3)
> XX
## [1] "HELLO_ONE_20_ME"    "GOODBYE_TWO_21_YOU" 
## [3] "HI_THREE_22_THEM"   "BYE_FOUR_23_US"    
## ------------------------------------------------
## process it
> spl <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(XX, "_"))[, 3:4]
> data.frame(cbind(XX, spl))
##                   XX V2   V3
## 1    HELLO_ONE_20_ME 20   ME
## 2 GOODBYE_TWO_21_YOU 21  YOU
## 3   HI_THREE_22_THEM 22 THEM
## 4     BYE_FOUR_23_US 23   US
```

Answer (score 0):

The obligatory `stringr` version of [@BrodieG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2725969/brodieg)'s quite spiffy answer:

```
df[c("match.1", "match.2")] <- 
  t(sapply(str_match_all(df$a, "^.*?_.*?_([0-9]+)_([[:alnum:]]+)$"), "[", 2:3))
```

Put here for context only. You should accept BrodieG's answer.